# Sublime Text 2: custom PATH and PYTHONPATH

Tags: environment-variables, development-environment, sublimetext

I'm using brew which installs python (2.7.2) in /usr/local/bin/
However, the default system python (2.7.1) is executed instead at `/usr/bin/`, which seems to be because it doesn't obey any of the bash PATH environment variables.
Also, it can't find my modules, as they are installed at `/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

I've been trying the following with `Python.sublime-settings`, but it doesn't work:

```
{
"path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
"env": ["PYTHONPATH", "/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages"],
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

How can I make Sublime Text obey these environment variables?

Comment: still can't make it work, did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: [docs for further details on build systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: For SublimeText3 build settings check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789410/how-to-edit-sublime-text3-build-settings

Answer (score 62):

env needs to be a JSON object, or dictionary if you will, like this:

```
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH":"/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand the format. I was able to fix my JAVA_HOME error with it like this: "env":{"JAVA_HOME":"$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"}

Answer (score 14):

I got it by setting my paths system wide by doing the following:

```
## PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:$PATH

## PYTHON
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH

# make systemwide
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
launchctl setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH
```

Edit:
Damn, this doesn't work for python, just for PYTHONPATH, when I try it, it still gives the wrong python. Code used to check python binary location:

```
import sys, os
print os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

Edit2:
Fixed this by hardlinking to the right python binary in Python.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Edit 3:

Debugging PYTHONPATH variable issues can be made easier by also printing `os.environ` at the top of your script. **Sublime Text 2 variable names apparently do NOT work for 'env'.**

Comment: I added the PYTHON now in .bash_profile, including your launchctl commands and in the Environment.plist file, but STILL both TM2 and ST2 can not find my PYTHONPATH. I want to tear my hair out... :(

Comment: Edit2 works, you can also put in the PYTHONPATH under an "env" dictionary, like in Bo's answer, i.e. add a comma and a new line reading `"env":{"PYTHONPATH": "/whatever/your/pythonpath/is"}` before the last `}`

Comment: Tried all of this, still getting `NameError: name 'python' is not defined`

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to bump an old post but if people land on this page looking for a way to make sublime2 use a custom $PATH so plugins (e.g a shell plugin) use your current systems $PATH this worked for me:

Create a file (plugin):

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Any_ol_name.py
```

Then paste this code in:

```
import os

# Tweak line below as needed for your $PATH
LOCAL = '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'

# Sublime's default path is
# /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
# it'll be prepended to your custom one
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['PATH'] += LOCAL

print 'PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH']
```

[Post with the original code here..](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/14/hacking-the-path-variable-in-sublime-text/)

This plugin will load when you start Sublime Text 2, I personnally used it to run shell commands like I would from terminal and to fix a few plugins that werent loading due to bad path variable.

Comment: This prints the correct PATH in Sublime's console, but it still can't find any commands like `python` or `coffee`. Still getting errors like `NameError: name 'python' is not defined`

Comment: The last line should have parentheses around the string value, or you might get a syntax error: print ('PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH'])

Comment: @NeilMonroe -- I had a similar issue, but I believe it is because I was using sublimetext 3 -- which uses python 3, where print is a function, and so need the parens.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old post but I landed here looking for this solution for Sublime Text 3. Just in case people land here as well, the quick solution is to go into ***Preferences.sublime-settings*** and add:

```
"additional_path_items": [
    "/path/to/add/1",
    "/path/to/add/2",
],
```