# Sublime Text 2 add module for PlugIn (MySQLdb)

Tags: python, sublimetext2, python-module

Im developing a small plugin for Sublime Text 2, but i need to use MySQLdb module. The MySQLdb module works fine from my normal CLI. But SB2 uses its own version of Python.

Any idea **how** i can install the MySQKdb module and **where** so SB2 can find it?

Python installation used /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on a plug-in today, and the solution I chose was to place the module within my package directory. In otherwords:

```
Packages
|  MyPackage
|  |  MyPackage.py
|  |  MySQLdb
|  |  | contents of MySQLdb package
```

You can change the PYTHONPATH that Sublime Text 2 uses, per these posts, but it seems there may be compatibility issues if you aren't careful.

[Sublime Text 2: custom PATH and PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574919/sublime-text-2-custom-path-and-pythonpath)

[Sublime Text2 Import error: No module named Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239839/sublime-text2-import-error-no-module-named-gnuplot)

This leads me to believe that the best solution would be to create a folder specifically for  downloading modules solely for the use of Sublime Text 2, and adding that to Sublime Text's PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Looking at "Package Control", I see that they added to sys.path in their main package .py file so that they could `import semver`. This is useful knowledge. I'll be digging into this more at some point.

Comment: Thanks. At the end I got it working by adjusting my local path, but this is a nice solution.