# Sublime Text2 Import error: No module named Gnuplot

Tags: python, gnuplot, sublimetext2, importerror

I'm trying to use Gnuplot in a Python script I'm writing in Sublime Text. Whenever I build, I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "..." line 4, in <module>
       import Gnuplot
ImportError: No module named Gnuplot
```

If I do the exact same code lines directly in Terminal, I have no problem importing and using Gnuplot.

The import error seems to be common, just with other modules. Usually the fix is related to PYTHONPATH. However, Gnuplot is on my computer located in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and should thus be found.

Anybody who's got a fix to this one?

Comment: Sublime Text2 comes bundled with its own Python interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 comes with its own Python interpreter which sets PYTHONPATH independently from the system Python interpreter you are referring to.

Please see this question how to set a different PYTHONPATH for Sublime. Please note that if the library you are using was compiled against a different Python version than Sublime is using loading the native dynamically linked libraries will probably cause Sublime Text 2 to crash.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919953/315168