# Not working autocomplete python module in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-module, sublime-anaconda

I reinstalled Sublime Text 3. Then I install plugins and noticed, what anaconda does not complement modules python.
When I write

```
import "module"
```

modules name is not diplayed!
I already have modules: Anaconda, Jedi, Python

I hope, your help me decide this problem

Comment: to import a module, you need to name the module. For example, to import the random module, you will give "import random"

Comment: Also look at this post. Does this answer your question.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050042/sublime-text-3-unable-to-import-python-module-although-importing-from-command-li