# Sublime Text2, python modules and AquaTerm

Tags: python, module, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text2 to write some script in Python, where I in the end want to plot some values with Gnuplot. After struggling with getting ST2 to find the Gnuplot module (solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919953/315168), I get this error message upon build:

```
gnuplot> set terminal aqua
                  ^
     line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

I *have* the AquaTerm installed, but just as with the Gnuplot module, ST2 seems to not communicate with much of my system. AquaTerm, as with Gnuplot, was installed using Macports, and is working smooth as silk with Terminal.

Is there a way to make ST2 primarily check the system, and then it's own packages upon build? Or am I missing out on something with ST2 here? My python.sublime-build file looks like this:

```
{
"path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/bin/python2.7"},
"cmd": ["python2.7", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: SublimeText2 executes whatever python you tell it to in the build settings; make sure it executes the correct one (system python vs. macports python).

Comment: This might be better served on the ST2 forums.

Comment: You're not trying to use the sublime text console, are you?

Comment: @Samoz: Noted! Though my experience is that Stackoverflow usually give quicker and better answers =)

Comment: @Eric: Uhm, maybe I am? I'm just running the standard build command.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I updated the post and included my python.sublime-build file contents. I believe I'm using the Macports installation of Python.

Comment: @Holene: not sure you should set `PYTHONPATH` *at all*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: removed the `PYTHONPATH` line, still get the error message about AquaTerm. Without the `"path"` line ST2 doesn't find the Gnuplot module.