# Grunt build with Sublime Text 2: process.env undefined

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2, gruntjs

When I run grunt from the command line, it works fine, but if I create a Sublime Text 2 build it "seems" to run fine except that anywhere process.env.SOME_VARIABLE is used it comes back as undefined.

Basically, from ST2 the following:

```
dest = process.env.CATALINA_HOME + "/webapps/MyApp/"
```

returns

```
"undefined/webapps/MyApp"
```

All of my files get copied to a new "undefined" directory in the project path rather than the Tomcat directory where it's supposed to be deployed to.

Is there any way to get Sublime Text 2 to respect/recognize node's process.env variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime is starting a new process to run your build that does not seem to have the environment variables set as you have in your command line.

You could use an extra **env** option in the build definition, where you pass the necessary environment variables to the new process.

It accepts a JSON object like this:

```
env: {"SOME_VARIABLE": "/full/path/to/something"}
```

You can take a look at the available options and some better description of the env option at this link: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html#options

Comment: Thanks! After your post I did a search for how to format the **env** option and found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574919/sublime-text-2-custom-path-and-pythonpath

Basically, env needs to be set up as a JSON object like so:

    env: {"CATALINA_HOME": "/full/path/to/tomcat"}

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I will also add the info to the answer, to make it more complete.