# Sublime text 2 can not find any python module

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2

I am leaning programming now and get stuck in the very beginning.

I have sublime text 2 installed on my Mac, and I type some python code in and it runs. However, when I start to import module like pandas/matplotlib, it can not find those modules. Certainly I have used pip to install them.

So what is the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Does Your code work with those modules when You use a different editor?

If it doesn't, Check if the modules You need are indeed installed. You can do this either by using the python prompt:

```
python
>>> help("modules")
>>> exit()
```

or using pip:

```
pip freeze
```

(sorry for posting this as an answer, but I'm currently not able to post comments)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sublime Text 2 gives importError: No module named pandas, whereas when I type code in terminal in MAC, it doesn't complain

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179268/pandas-installed-but-cannot-be-found-why-is-that.

Comment: I have created another build file, as my terminal is showing python 2.7.11 and sublime text 2 showing 2.7.10, but it doesn't help

Comment: did You try to change the PYTHONPATH variable like is suggested in the article above: Once Anaconda is installed, its Python distribution supercedes the Python distribution that ships with OS X. You've installed Pandas on the former distribution (or rather, it's come pre-installed), while Sublime Text is relying on the latter distribution to build and run.

You'll want to modify Sublime Text to use the Python distribution from Anadonda. You can modify Python.sublime-settings as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574919/sublime-text-2-custom-path-and-pythonpath