# trouble with Sublime REPL not finding packages

Tags: macos, python-2.7, sublimetext2, python-module, sublimerepl

What I've got:
New copy of Yosemite, homebrew installation of python 2.7, Sublime Text 2 with the following packages: LaTex tools, Package Control, Rbox, and SublimeREPL. I downloaded package feedparser with Pip.

I'm new to python (and any coding beyond R) and I'm trying to set up a good workflow with Sublime Text 2. For some reason, when I try and load feedparser in the sublime REPL python window, I get "import error, no module named feedparser".

However, I can get the packaged to load from python in the terminal.

`which python` in terminal I get back `usr/local/bin/python` which is where homebrew puts python.

I have a limited understanding of this stuff, but I'm assuming its because REPL is using the old version of python that comes with OSX.

I tried changing the environment variable in the Python.sublime-build file according to this post (first answer):

[Sublime Text 2: custom PATH and PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574919/sublime-text-2-custom-path-and-pythonpath/9919953#9919953)

Yet, it still does not work. Maybe I did it wrong? I'm not sure.

With the number of people using Sublime text and Python I know that this must get dealt with all of the time. I've lots of posts with people suggesting many different things and I'm fairly lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new menu item to **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python`**. First, open your `Packages/User` directory by selecting **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** and opening the `User` directory. Create a folder in `User` called `SublimeREPL`, inside that create a `config` directory, and inside that create a `Python` directory. Finally, make a new file in Sublime with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "caption": "SublimeREPL",
                "mnemonic": "r",
                "id": "SublimeREPL",
                "children":
                [
                    {
                        "caption": "Python",
                        "id": "Python",
                        "children":
                        [
                            {
                                "command": "repl_open",
                                "caption": "Python (Homebrew)",
                                "id": "repl_python",
                                "mnemonic": "p",
                                "args": 
                                {
                                    "type": "subprocess",
                                    "encoding": "utf8",
                                    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-i", "-u"],
                                    "cwd": "/Users/williamrudisill/Development/python",
                                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                    "external_id": "python",
                                    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Save this file as `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`. Make sure you edit the `"cwd"` parameter to set the folder you'd like the interpreter to open in.

Now, if you open **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python`** there will be an item called **`Python (Homebrew)`** that you can use to open an interpreter with `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: YES!!! Thanks, this absolutely worked. I appreciate the very explicit instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For **Mac OSX [Racket 6.03] [Sublime Text 3]**

For those interested in RACKET (DR RACKET) Repl, and are recieving an error when launching the repl "file not found".. I found out -- after spending a couple hours trying to reconfigure files -- the solution..

Open Dr Racket.
-> Help -> Configure Command Line for Racket -> click "ok" box. 
   *-Done.*

Launch the Repl in Sublime Text.