# No module named 'statsmodels' when running python in sublime text CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, sublimetext, statsmodels

I'm running python 3.6 and have statsmodels installed in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages however when I try to import statsmodels in python I get the error: "No module named 'statsmodels'". Can someone explain what I'm supposed to do?

I'm using Sublime Text's built in command line interface.

Comment: what is the output of running `pip freeze | grep statsmodels` in your terminal?

Comment: @briancaffey it returns `statsmodels==0.8.0`

Comment: OK. are you running the code in a Jupyter notebook environment and/or with a virtual environment?

Comment: @briancaffey No I'm running it locally

Comment: It is not necessary, but I don't have much other information about why the import is failing. One more idea: run the following command in the python interpreter you are using: `import sys; sys.executable`. what is the output?

Comment: @briancaffey /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161676/discussion-between-briancaffey-and-bernardo-rodriguez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Sublime Text's CLI and your terminal point to different versions of Python.

In your terminal the result of `import sys; sys.executable` is

```
/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python'
```

but in the Sublime Text CLI you would see:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python‌​3
```

The Sublime Text CLI python path does not have the `statsmodels` package whereas the anaconda python does. It is possible to change the default python path in Sublime Text. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574919/sublime-text-2-custom-path-and-pythonpath) for more details on how to do that. I would recommend just running python from your terminal and not the sublime text CLI to keep things simple.